# Incorrect double values returned from mysql to java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

So I was trying to read some double values from mysql to java.
I am using a mybatis mapper to read my values and return the value as a map.

When I run my query in sql, my value comes out to be `-42295.8451869851` but when I use mybatis to pick the same from a query and put it in a java Hashmap the value changes to  `{Double@25327}-42295.84518699004` . Why is this anomaly and what can I do to prevent it?

This is the mybatis query line I am using:
I am using the class `org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession`;

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myListMaps =  getSqlSession().selectList(QUERY_NAME, queryParameters);
```

Edit: After looking at few responses, I realize that I need to somwhow use bigDecimal instead of Double/Float. So I will reframe my question to solve my purpose here. Is there any way to tell mybatis that a certain sql type is to be mapped to BigDecimal instead of Double/Float in a HashMap?

I also have other values being picked up from sql like `integer` and `varchar` that are being converted to the required types of `integer` and `string` in java automatically and I want them picked as it is. Just need to change the doubles to bigdecimal.

Comment: `double` is approximate. For exact numbers use `decimal`

Comment: 'certain sql type' is not OK. As @juergend pointed out, you must use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` as the column type and if you do, MyBatis will map the value to `BigDecimal` without any extra configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is expected for the floating point number. You can read how the IEEE 754 works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754.

But I think there is another issue happening. You say that the number is double (64-bit), but based on the result it look that it gets converted to float(32-bit)

```
-42295.8451869851 -> 0xC0E4A6FB0BC59380 (64bit) - 0xC72537D8 (32bit)

-42295.84518699004 -> 0xC0E4A6FB0BC59627 (64bit)- 0xC72537D8 (32bit)
```

If you want to keep the precision correct then you need to define it correctly both in DB and then in Java use `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html`

Answer (score 1):

Use BigDecimal if you need precision [doc](http://mybatis.org/generator/configreference/javaTypeResolver.html).