# How to map a sql type to java type using Mybatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

So my java is sending a query to SQL which is returning multiple fields. Some of the fields are being returned as `DOUBLE` to java because their type in SQL is `FLOAT`/`NUMERIC`. This is causing precision issues. I want mybatis to map the `DOUBLE` directly to `BIGDECIMAL`. What would be the way to get this done?

My Mybatis resultmap:

```
    <resultMap id="newResultMap" type="java.util.HashMap" autoMapping="true">
        <association property="someObject" resultMap="someObjectMap" />
    </resultMap>
```

Comment: Please explain how can I reproduce the 'precision issue'. I read your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63841429/1261766) and tested it, but couldn't reproduce the issue i.e. if the column is `DOUBLE` and its value is `-42295.8451869851`, the HashMap returned from a query contains `java.lang.Double` of `-42295.8451869851`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that by `precision issue` you mean case when `NUMERIC` value has more that 16 significant digits (the max number of significant digits for `double` in java)?

Comment: Would `jdbcType=BIGDECIMAL` in the resultMap help? This should force the result to be created with `new BigDecimal(VALUE)`.    Or you could use an actual Object, instead of a Map with the type of BigDecimal.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to write your own custom Handler.